# Using SWIG to return Byte[] causing jvm to segv on exit

Tags: java, c++, jvm, swig

I added a method to a class to return a null terminated 
set of bytes.  I wished to return a byte[] in java
As a result of this change the function seems to work
wonderfully as far as returning the bytes, But the
jvm crashes with a segv on exit.
I printed "exiting main" which showed up in the output
and then the segv occurred

C++ class

```
class squid {
 const signed char* getBytes()
}
```

squidx.i

```
%typemap(jni) const signed char*        "jbyteArray"
%typemap(jtype) const signed char*      "byte[]"
%typemap(jstype) const signed char*     "byte[]"
%typemap(out) const signed char*
{
   long lSize = strlen($);

   // create a new byte[] object in Java
   jbyteArray data = JCALL1(NewByteArray, jenv, lSize);

   // copy pixels from the image buffer
   JCALL4(SetByteArrayRegion, jenv, data, 0, lSize, (jbyte*)result);

   $result = data;
}

// change Java wrapper mapping for unsigned char*
%typemap(javaout) const signed char* {
    return $jnicall;
}
```

result of java -version

java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pxa6470sr5-20130619_01(SR5))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 Linux amd64-64 Compressed References 20130617_152572 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR5_20130617_1436_B152572
JIT  - r11.b04_20130528_38954ifx1
GC   - R26_Java726_SR5_20130617_1436_B152572_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20130617_152572)
JCL - 20130616_01 based on Oracle 7u25-b12

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `java/typemaps.i` from the SWIG distribution. Probably it already contains required typemaps. Check `OUTPUT_TYPEMAP` or `INOUT_TYPEMAP` for the reference implementation.

Comment: Nope typemaps.i   only deals with pointers via typemap(argout)

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was an interaction with other threads that still existed in the native world
It had nothing to do with java at all.